How do I add an annotation for a reprinted work in bibliography?
I need to cite a chapter from a book which was reprinted in APA style. It is supposed to look like this (https://www.bibguru.com/g/apa-reprinted-book-citation/):

Author(s) of the chapter. (Year of publication). Title of the chapter. In: Author(s) of the book (Ed.), Title of the book (pages). Publisher. (Original work published Year of original publication)

I am not able to create the line (Original work published Year of original publication) at the end of the citation. Best I could do was to use annote to get this line BUT then this line is printed in the next line and with a "." at the end.
I also need to inline cite like this: (Author(s) of the chapter, Year of publication/Original year of publication) as can be seen here: https://libguides.ucentralasia.org/c.php?g=720037&p=5134126
Here is an MWE:

tex

\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber,natbib=true,url=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
    Text from source \citep{Author12024}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}


test.bib (I run biber)

@InCollection{Author12024,
  author    = {Author1},
  booktitle = {title of book},
  publisher = {publisher},
  title     = {title of article},
  year      = {2024},
  editor    = {editor},
  pages     = {1--10},
  annote    = {(Original work published 1999)},
}

This is how it looks like:

Quotation inline and in bibliography is not like stated above.

As a general point, I would recommend not to rely on third-party interpretations of APA style. Sometimes those are outdated or outright wrong, because they miss the finer (more confusing) points of APA style. Consult the manual or the official APA website (which contains quite a few examples, if not everything that the manual has to offer). In this case https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/book-references#3 looks like a good start.
biblatex-apa comes with an extensive example .bib file called biblatex-apa-test-references.bib that shows entries for all examples in the manual. For a republished book we find for example
@BOOK{10.2:28,
  AUTHOR         = {J. Piaget and B. Inhelder},
  TRANSLATOR     = {H. Weaver},
  EDITION        = {2},
  TITLE          = {The Psychology of the Child},
  PUBLISHER      = {Basic Books},
  DATE           = {1969},
  ORIGDATE       = {1966}
}

So building on that, you may want to try
\documentclass[american,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber,]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@InCollection{Author12024,
  author    = {Author1},
  booktitle = {title of book},
  publisher = {publisher},
  title     = {title of article},
  year      = {2024},
  editor    = {editor},
  pages     = {1--10},
  origdate  = {1999},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Text from source \autocite{Author12024}.
  \printbibliography
\end{document}


Do note that if the chapter was reprinted from another book (as shown in https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/examples/edited-book-chapter-references#2), a different approach would be more appropriate (https://github.com/plk/biblatex-apa/blob/7fa19dcd3604dac18a2c25dad08f242d5a49ce72/bibtex/bib/biblatex-apa-test-references.bib#L1245-L1268)

I should probably have mentioned that the \DeclareLanguageMapping{ngerman}{ngerman-apa} line (which I removed in my answer) has been obsolete for many years and should be removed.
